# Enclosing every CSV field that having commas in between with double quotes in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to enclose the each field value in double quotes using csv module.
But here the trick is we do have commas in between the values which needs to be skipped.
This is the snippet i am using to enclose the values in quotes.

Data:

```
col1,col2
first row,This section of the badge focuses on Communications
second row,Feedback has partnered with team members, leaders, and executives receive confidential, anonymous feedback
```

Code snippet

```
import csv

with open('data.csv') as input, open('out.csv','w') as output:
    reader = csv.reader(input)
    writer = csv.writer(output, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    for line in reader:
        writer.writerow(line)
```

Output

```
"col1","col2"
"first row","This section of the badge focuses on Communications"
"second row","Feedback has partnered with team members"," leaders"," and executives receive confidential"," anonymous feedback"
```

Expected output

```
"col1","col2"
"first row","This section of the badge focuses on Communications"
"second row","Feedback has partnered with team members, leaders, and executives receive confidential, anonymous feedback"
```

Comment: Why not using  "\"," as a delimiter ?

Comment: How many columns do you have in your real csv file?

Comment: @Tbaki Thats how our customer API was created, where they are using delimiter as comma

Comment: @Corralien its actually 2

Comment: @jennie if you have "," in your data set and "," in your data, it's not a good practice to use that as a delimiter, try to ask them to change it to something not present in the data set if you can contact them;

Comment: @Tbaki I totally agree with your proposal but i dont have an option to contact them :-(

Comment: The Python `csv` module does exactly this if you only manage to _read_ the (mangled, ambiguous) data correctly in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Since the input data is not a regular CSV file, there may be a problem to read the input file using the `csv` module.
To solve the problem, you may directly read the lines of the file and then parse them as follows:

```py
import csv

with open('data.csv') as fin, open('out.csv','w') as fout:
    writer = csv.writer(fout, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    for line in fin:
        writer.writerow(line.rstrip().split(',', 1))
```

Comment: When i am executing the same snippet on full file, i am facing below error.  
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u200b' in position 168: character maps to <undefined>

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DictReader` and `DictWriter` with the `restkey` attribute:

```
with open('data.csv') as inp, open('out.csv', 'w') as out:
    reader = csv.DictReader(inp, restkey='colN')
    writer = csv.DictWriter(out, fieldnames=reader.fieldnames,
                            delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    writer.writeheader()
    for line in reader:
        line[reader.fieldnames[-1]] += ','.join(line.pop('colN', []))
        writer.writerow(line)
```

Content of `out.csv`:

```
"col1","col2"
"first row","This section of the badge focuses on Communications"
"second row","Feedback has partnered with team members leaders, and executives receive confidential, anonymous feedback"
```

Comment: When i am executing the same snippet on full file, i am facing below error.  
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u200b' in position 168: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: Try to use `encoding='latin1'` (or 'utf-8') as argument of two `open` files